# CodeIgniter 3 and sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I updated to CodeIgniter 3 recently, following this guide:
[CI3: upgrade 3.0 from 2.2.1](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html).

I set up this configuration in application/config/config.php file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session_my_site';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 604800; // 1 week
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Is there something wrong here? My session is destroyed after a few hours...

Comment: You're using files for the session driver, but you set the path to null? Also, you say a few hours, is that 5 hours by any chance (5 hours in minutes is 300)?

Comment: I'm not sure about the time (is there a way to know exactly ?).
Should i set a value for the path ? I thought it was just for sessions stored in database.

Comment: Look at your link. It says that if you want to use 'files' you have to set sess_save_path, so it can't be null

Comment: They do not give any example or am i wrong ? It's written : "Set a $config['sess_save_path'] value. For the ‘database’ driver, a fallback to $config['sess_table_name'] is in place, but otherwise requires you to read the manual for the specific driver of your choice." I just don't understand what i should write into this variable. Can you give me some examples ?

Comment: @Maxime I've never played with that driver, but according to the doc, you just need to set the relative path to some folder where your sessions files will be stored. Look here : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html . Question, do you really need this ? I have a CI3 project and I didn't went through those considerations regarding sessions.

Comment: @AdrienXL ok i'll try ! But do you use sessions into your CI3 project ?
If so, did you try to change the time before session is over ?

Comment: @Maxime Yes I do and yes i did change time expiration and it worked correctly. FWIW, I use 'cookie' as sess_driver.

Comment: @AdrienXL i tried to put 'cookie' instead of 'files' and it prints me an error into logs ...

Comment: @Maxime here is my current config file for on of my CI3 project : http://pastebin.com/kbFTMZgv . It uses database but you can set it to false. If that still doesn't work, it might be because you miss something while doing your migration.

Comment: Oh I forgot, in your question you said that your session expire after three hours. But are you aware that expires after xx time of inactivity ?

Comment: @AdrienXL, sorry for being that noob with that problem, i really don't understand what's happening here ... I'm used to CI and i never struggle for **** like that before ! Anyway thanks for your patience and to put your file on pastebin ! I tried to make the same conf as you it seems that cookie is not supported anymore in CI 3 as sess_driver ... I did not understand your sentence : "But are you aware that expires after xx time of inactivity ?" what do you mean ?

Comment: @Maxime Thx ! You're right, cookie are not valid anymore, as I use database, codeigniter switched to database driver as cookie doesn't exists. That's a terrible copy/paste error I've made here. Also, what I meant is that codeigniter's session stores the timestamp of your user's last activity. The framework use this information to calculate every $config['sess_time_to_update'] the new expiration time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your save path you need to set up a location folder. Use `'files'` as session driver preferred. As like below I have set up a cache to store sessions in BASE PATH which is setting folder. Make sure you have auto loaded sessions and `$config['encryption_key'] = ''` add key.

You can set up a database sessions but this works just as well. Make sure folder permissions 0700

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/search.html?q=session&check_keywords=yes&area=default

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'yourfoldername/cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Once that is done then you should be able to do something like.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$data_session_set = array('logged' => 1, 'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 'user_id' => $this->user_auth->get_id()); 
$this->session->set_userdata($data_session_set);
```

Comment: Thank you mustang83, but where should i create the folder ? into application ? my basepath is : /home/maxime/Documents/informatique/perso/my_project/system/. It's kinda weird to have sessions stored into system no ?

Comment: I find it more secure that way. That's the only reason why I have important stuff stored in systems.

Comment: Ok thx, i tried to add the folder and i can now see a file in it. I'll let you know tomorrow if it's ok ! :)

Comment: Thx to both of you AdrienXL & mustang83 ! It seems problem is solved with the 'sess_save_path' and the folder to save the cache, i was struggling with that ! cheers :)

Comment: All ways good when you log out to unlink files in your sessions so does not full up and makes site slow.

Comment: It will still leave one file in there even if unlink all session files it just a regenerate so is ok.

Comment: How to clear the session folder.There are lot of files created.

Answer (score 9):

In application/config/config.php set this value:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code it work.

```
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
        if(session_id() == '') session_start();
    } else  {
       if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 different values and somehow they worked, it depends on the version of Centos:

For Centos 6.X I used:

In application/config/config.php set this value:

$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;

For Centos 7.X I used:

$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();

it will not work if you move your app from one server version to another without editing this value.