# CodeIgniter cannot use session data after redirect()

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I was trying to build an application but I faced a problem with the session data. So I downloaded a new fresh CodeIgniter project and tried to work with the session but still failed. Here's what I did:

**application/config/autoload.php:**

```php
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**application/config/config.php:**

```php
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'D:\Projects\CodeIgnter-fresh\application\cache\session';
```

After that I created a controller called *User.php*

**User.php**

```php
<?php

class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->session->set_userdata('somedata', 'somevalue');
        redirect('user/dashboard', 'refresh');
    }

    public function dashboard() {
        var_dump($this->session->userdata);
    }
}
```

The controller contains two simple methods. The *index* method sets some user data and after that redirects to the other method, which dumps the userdata. Unfortunately here's what I see:
[image]
It seems the only data I am able to see is some CodeIgniter data, but for sure the data I am trying to set is gone. **Interesting thing I noticed** was that in *application/cache/session* folder I can see some files with my data in it. So I guess it has to be some permission problem, but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

I'm using:
OS: Windows 10 Education
PHP version: 7.2.11
CodeIgniter version: 3.1.10

Comment: what CI version and PHP version are you using?

Comment: Excuse me, I missed that information. My CodeIgniter version is 3.1.10 and my PHP version is 7.2.11

Comment: `$config['sess_save_path']`  is set wrong, can't be `D:\etc`; see answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385783/codeigniter-3-and-sessions

Comment: Nice catch, but the problem still exists...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756370/codeigniter-session-is-not-working-on-php-7 Check This Answer and Try it....I hope You help

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues in this question:

1. not being able to write the session information to the disk using CI
   file driver
   and
2. not being able to retrieve the session information

**1. write the session information to the disk**

The config.php at around line 344 says

> 'sess_save_path'
>
> The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
>
> For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
>     WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
>
> IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!

Therefore you need to set it either to false (nothing is saved) or use an absolute path. In order to make this work **for development and production alike**, you can use the PHP `$_SERVER` array and use it in your config.php like:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/cache/session/';
```

finally you need to make sure, that above directory is writable, but only you have access to that directory (on production server).

P.S.: you see what's in $_SERVER using this line:

```
<?php echo'<pre>';print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

**2. retrieve the session information**

- make sure that you don't destroy the session in a previous function
- keep in mind changing $config['cookie_domain'], $config['cookie_path'], 
  $config['cookie_secure'] can affect sessions:

this setting works on my setup:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/application/cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

If none of this works, you can still try to override autoload, putting this constructor into your `User` controller:

```
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Comment: That's correct for sure. But I'm still not getting the session data, the result remains the same.. How can I check the permitions of the folder?

Comment: I answered the question, as I thought you cannot store the session on your server using the 'files' driver. I just looked again at your dashboard function. It should be `var_dump( $this->session->userdata() );`

Comment: No matter what I dump: `$this->session->userdata` , `$this->session->userdata()` or even `$_SESSION` , I still get the same result...

Comment: but do you see the file in /application/cache/session/ ?

Comment: Yes, I can see it

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce this on my side, I used your functions and output is: array(8) {
  ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
  int(1559151567)
..etc...
  ["somedata"]=>
  string(9) "somevalue"
}; maybe clear cache, or try in another browser?

Comment: one more thing comes in my mind, did you change the default cookie config?

Answer (score 0):

Set The Driver to 'files' in config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

Further Information here [Codeigniter Session User Manual](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sess_driver)

Comment: Actually it is set to 'files' by default, so the solution must be somewhere else :/